# overlay not taking full screen after window height resizing

Tags: html, css

I have a css and html codes below

```
.overlay_ {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

html

> ```
>  <body> <div class="overlay_"></div> </body>
> ```

The problem is when I resize the window the overlay will not be taking the full screen. I need it to be full screen despite resizing the window height.

[image]

Comment: maybe  set the body selector to  `padding:0`  `margin:0 ` and  `width:100vw; ` and  `height: 100vh ` I think will help you

Comment: I already did that to no avail.

Comment: can you send a photo with the problem, maybe also a paint on it (also on microsoft paint)

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas streamable.com/3ebcv6

Comment: ok. use `position: fixed` with `top:0;` `left: 0;`

Answer (score 2):

## new modified answer

add this to your css:

```css
.overlay_ { 
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

`fixed` make the element stay in his place, even if document is scrolled!

> if this help you, please upvote for help more people

## previous answer ...

I added this css to your code:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.overlay_ {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="overlay_"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

### before

[image]

### after

[image]

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.overlay_ {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="overlay_"></div>
</body>

</html>
```